# Android-RecyclerView with videos and images

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

### Requirements:

I want to achieve recyclerview having images and videos just like instagram, LinkedIn and facebook apps.

Only the visible video should auto-play.

If the video is playing and I switch the app and come back again the video should resume.

So far I tried with these two libraries but no luck.

1. [Play video in ListView or RecyclerView](https://github.com/waynell/VideoListPlayer)
2. [VideoPlayerManager](https://github.com/danylovolokh/VideoPlayerManager)

Any help would be appreciated.